# Connect to a Symfony application through CURL

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, curl

I have an application built in Symfony. I have another application in PHP and trying to check if the current user has any account in the Symfony application and authenticate him to obtain the PHPSessionID? In this case I use *CURL* command as below. How ever the username and password is correct but still the symfony application redirect me to the login page. Does anybody know how can I fix this?

```
$cred_data = array('_username' => 'test1', '_password' => '123', '_target_path' => 'http://symfonyappdomain/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/Acme/HomePage');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://symfonyappdomain/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/Acme/login_check');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($cred_data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Appreciate it

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will solve the issue ... but as far as i remember: curl requests to github fail if you don't provide a `User-Agent` header. Did you set the **user_agent** directive in your `php.ini` ?

Comment: Thanks for response, I added the user_agent through CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER but not in php.ini and it did not work (still same)

Comment: csrf protection is one definite reason your current request fails. You have to disable it in `config.yml` or get it by crawling the token from a previous GET request to the login-page. Further you have to make sure that the **session-cookie** actually gets re-used with subsequent requests. Otherwise you'll be logged out automatically and therefore redirected to the login-page. That could be the second issue you're having. With csrf-protection enabled you'll **never** be able to login without requesting a token first and then adding to the subsequent POST request to your login-form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix this issue. In order to authenticate a user through another app we need to create another firewall in **security.yml** with different pattern using form_login but **required_previous_session** needs to be disabled, check this:

```
app_auth:
    pattern: ^acme/auth/application
    form_login:
        provider: same_provider_name #or use different provider
        login_path: /acme/auth/application/login
        check_path: /acme/auth/application/login_check
        require_previous_session: false
    anonymous: true
    context: my_shared_context_name

main_auth:
    pattern:     ^/acme
    form_login:  
        provider: same_provider_name #or use a different provider
        login_path: /acme/login
        check_path: /acme/login_check
    logout:
    path:   /acme/logout
    target: /acme
    security: true
    context: my_shared_context_name
```

Please pay attention to that the **context** of each firewall needs to be same otherwise you won't be able to use same SessionID in both firewall.
I guess it is possible to use *required_previous_session* just in the main firewall and not to create another firewall, but I did not try (because I am not sure and I think it's much more secured to have separate firewall for authentication from outside)

Comment: Just in case: for this one you won't need to disable **CSRF Protection**

Comment: Do not forget to create routing for **acme/auth/application/login** and **acme/auth/application/login_check**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the **[CSRF protection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection)** kicks in if you POST to the login-form directly without without obtaining the token from a previous GET request to your login-route and including it in your POST request.

Either disable CSRF protection for your login-form (not the best solution) ...

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'csrf_protection' => false,
         // ...
    ));
}
```

... or disable it globally (definitely not a good idea)

```
# app/config/config.yml

framework:
    csrf_protection:
        enabled: false
```

... or issue a GET request to the login-form first, then parse the response and include the CSRF-token that was created in the following POST-Request. Make sure to include the session-cookie in the subsequent request otherwise the token can't be validated because it's saved in the session.

... or implement a different solution i.e. create a listener that deactivates the CSRF protection **only** if a certain request header is present.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nifr; I pick the last solution which I think is more reliable due to security issues. I think this will solve my problem, I will post and confirm when it's done :)

Comment: Looking forward to your feedback :) You can find inspiration for that in the FOSRestBundle. It has a configuration-option named `disable_csrf`. The corresponding class is **[DisableCSRFExtension](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Form/Extension/DisableCSRFExtension.php)**.

Comment: Hey @nifr; I tried disabling CSRF_protection in config.yml just to test if it works, but still redirecting me to login page. I thought I have to submit a csrf token through my post request in CURL. Now the question is that how can I create a custom csrf token? Therefore, I posted this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075065/create-custom-unique-csrf-token-in-symfony)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you understood the way the token works... You  **can't** generate the token externally (in your other PHP application). A new token is created and **stored in the session** every time a new form is constructed inside the symfony2 application. With CSRF protection in place you **can't** send a valid POST request to a form without visiting the page containing the form before !

Comment: I understood the way the token works, when login page is hit it creates the different unique token and on submit will be posted to login_check. The thing I am looking for was understanding  or changing the way Symfony produce the token so that I produce the same token in another application and send it; e.g if could change producing process of token to: *md5(username.pass)*
On the other hand I disabled CSRF in config.yml then I thought it might be due to the SessionID so I used [http://www.telerik.com/fiddler](fiddler) and compose same request same header, still redirecting to login page!!