# Create custom unique csrf token in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, csrf

Do anyone know how can I create unique CSRF_token in Symfony? I used the following config in my security.yml file and in the form it creates the default Symfony CSRF_token.

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false
    docova:
        pattern:     /.*
        form_login:
            login_path: %d.login_path%
            check_path: %d.check_path%
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            csrf_parameter: _csrf_token
            intention: My_Private_String
            default_target_path: %d.default_target_path%
            success_handler: myproject.security.authentication.success_handler
        logout:
            path:   /MyProject/logout
            target: /MyProject
        anonymous: true
        security: true
        docova: true
```

and in my login twig file I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
```

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

the csrf token generation is based on the name of the form and the session id, thus the csrf is unique for each form per session as it is, if you want something truly unique for every form, you'd need to basically override the method that creates the csrf and pass in a randomized string in place of the form name.  You'd then need to save that randomized string and match it with the session id so you can validate the csrf when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thaks for your response. The only reason for that is I want to use the csrf_token in another application so that I submit the credential of user and the csrf_token to the login_check using CURL or php_stream_context_create and get the PHPSessionID after authentication. It seems even by posting csrf_token Symfony does not authenticate and redirect me to the login page.